# Javascript simple math error

Tags: javascript, math

I can't understand whats causing this, although math has never been my specialty so any help is appreciated. My simple equation is in two parts:

Answer 1)  226 - [value] multiplied by .9

Answer 2)  226 - [value] multiplied by .55

If you use 40 as the input value, my calculator says:

Answer 1) 226 - 40 = 186 * .9 = **167.4**

Answer 2) 226 - 40 = 186 * .55 = **102.3**

But my code says:

Answer 1) **190**

Answer 2) **204**

My Code:

```
HTML:
<input id="HR"size="4" value="" /><span id="number"></span>
 Answer 1 <strong><span id="answer1"></span></strong><br>
 Answer 2 <strong><span id="answer2"></span></strong>
</p>

<a href="#" class='THR'>click to calculate</a>

Script:
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $('a.THR').click(function() {
     var value = parseInt( $( "#HR" ).val() );
     $( "#answer1" ).html( 226 - value * 0.9 );
     $( "#answer2" ).html( 226 - value * 0.55 );
     return false;
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: Note that the statement `226 - 40 = 186 * .9` is also simply incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are forgetting order of operations.  Multiplication has higher precedence than addition/subtraction.  Put parenthesis around your `226-value`

```
 $( "#answer1" ).html( (226 - value) * 0.9 );
 $( "#answer2" ).html( (226 - value) * 0.55 );
```

Rereading your question, I'm not sure what exactly your desired result is.  If you want to do the multiplication first and then the subtraction, you don't need the parenthesis, though it may be helpful to write `226 - (value * 0.9)` to make it clear.  What is happening on your calculator though is that you are typing `226 - value` and then multiplying that result by your decimal number.  So the above code, `(226 - value) * 0.9`, represents your typing.  It may help to describe what you are trying to do from the end user's perspective to decide where your parentheses go.

Comment: Seems like a silly, little thing to overlook, but it can have a huge impact. I had a client years ago for whom we'd built an inventory system. Data was uploaded and priced by the system built by another developer. Final pricing was off by $1,000s in some cases. After I checked the algorithm the client had given us, I found the dev had made a few Order of Operation mistakes. A few parenthesis later, the client was very happy.

Comment: @Sean you've asked this question a few times.  You should probably go back and accept the correct response to help whoever looks at it in the future.

Comment: Hi Dennis, it's actually variations on the same question as I stumbled over several little obstacles. I've tried to highlight the uniqueness of my individual ineptitude's with each one.

Comment: Dennis, is there a simple way to truncate the result to one decimal place, or is this a new question?

Comment: @Sean It should be, but it's simple.  `var five = 5; five.toFixed(1)` will give you a string `"5.0"`

Comment: Hey Dennis, I couldn't get your example to round off, but I did manage to get the code working with this: 


      $('a.THR').click(function() {

      var value = parseInt( $( "#HR" ).val() );

      var answer1 = (226 - value) * 0.9;

      var answer2 = (226 - value) * 0.55;

     $( "#answer1" ).html(answer1.toFixed(1));

     $( "#answer2" ).html(answer2.toFixed(1));

     return false ;

     });

Answer (score 5):

Parentheses: you need them.

```
 $( "#answer1" ).html( (226 - value) * 0.9 );
 $( "#answer2" ).html( (226 - value) * 0.55 );
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiplication takes precedence over substraction.
Hence the expressions will be interpreted as:

Answer 1) **226 - ([value] multiplied by .9 )**
e.g:

```
226 - (40 *0.9) = 226 - 36 = 190
```

Answer 2) **226 - ([value] multiplied by .55)**
e.g:

```
226 - (40 * .55) = 226 - 22 = 204
```

Answer (score 1):

You're code is honoring the standard order of operations:

- Parentheses,
- Exponeniation,
- Multiplcation/Division
- Addition/Subtraction

...but you are not. Parenthesize your equation to change the order to what you want.

Comment: There is no exponentiation operator in JavaScript, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an order-of-operations issue (nothing to do with jquery). Multiplication/division is performed before addition/subtraction. So:

```
226 - 40*.9 = 226 - 36 = 190
```

Answer (score 1):

In math, multiplication takes precedence over addition and subtraction. Use parentheses to clarify:

```
$( "#answer1" ).html( (226 - value) * 0.9 );
$( "#answer2" ).html( (226 - value) * 0.55 );
```

Comment: Yes, you have to answer the question within five seconds of posting or your too late, haha. Thanks though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Ha - well that's what I like about SO - plenty of good advice. Thanks for upvoting.